# How to add access to EKS aws-auth config map for users managed by IAM Identity Center

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to authenticate users managed in AWS IAM Identity Center to AWS EKS (being in different AWS account then IAM Identity Center). Correct me if I'm wrong but IAM Idenity Center maps permissions (set as permission sets in account A) to roles in account B. So basically users assume role in the target account. I though that because of that I could just add role into aws-auth config map but that doesn't work, ie. as a user with assumed role I cannot see resources in AWS EKS console. The part I've added:

```
- groups:
  - system:masters
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_yyyyy // this is role which seems to be assumed by user configured in Identity Center
  username: AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_yyyyy
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find out the solution? because i'm facing the same issue

Comment: Yes, so solution is to use `rolaarn` in format like so: `arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_yyyyy`

Comment: But the yyyy can change with time?

Comment: No, I don't think it will change. When do you think it could change?

Answer (score 4):

Just if anyone is looking for the solution I'm anwering my question:
`rolearn` should have a format of: `arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_yyyyy`

Comment: How did you find this? Is this even documented?

Comment: @0xFED5550 May 24, 2023 at 22:15, here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html
It states:
"rolearn: The ARN of the IAM role to add. This value can't include a path. For example, you can't specify an ARN such as arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/my-team/developers/role-name. The ARN needs to be arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/role-name instead.
"